# Hibernate: EntityManager.merge does not insert any data

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, merge, persistence, entitymanager

i have some trouble with hibernate. The EntityManager.merge() does not have any effect, neither does persist().

My code:

```
@Stateless
public class UserManager {

@Inject
private EntityManager em;

public User save(User user){
    return em.merge(user);
}
}
```

The User entity is pretty simple:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6249050000984099316L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;

//some more fields
//...

// getters / setters following
//...
}
```

My ManagedBean is just calling `userManager.save(user)` and passing a user-object.

The User-Table in my database is completely empty, so i expect `merge()` to result in an INSERT statement.
There is neither an insert nor an update on table User.
Only the next_val for the generated ID is updated:

```
INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-7) Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-7) Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

EntityManager Producer:

```
public class Resources {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @Produces
   public EntityManager produceEntityManager()
   {
      return em;
   }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/dkmgr</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor"
                value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using EJB maybe you should try this:

```
public User save(User user){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(user);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return user;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am using EJB, so there is no @Transactional annotation :-/
What do you mean by 'paste your app-context'?

Comment: I changed my answer. By paste you app-context.xml I mean config files with entityManagerFactory itp

Comment: begin() / commit() works! Thanks for that. Is there any workaround so i would not need this begin()/commit() for every merge-operation in my application? I've added my persistence.xml and the EM-Producer to my question above. But I don't have any app-context.xml, should I be worried about that?

Comment: by the way, why do I need to begin the transaction manually, since my EntityManager is Container-Managed?

Comment: I don't know. I'm using Spring and very often problem with persist() and merge() is caused by missing @Transactional annotation. Sometimes because of wrong <context:component-scan> usage.
I don't know EJB so much, maybe you have to create some super class for persist(), merge() and other common datebase operations.

Comment: I am getting `getTransaction() cannot be called on a container managed entity` error.

Comment: Propably you are using <tx:annotation-driven/> in your configuration file. It means, you can use transactions only in declarative mode.